# Google Maps API -is not showing all cities

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I would like to use Google Maps API to find all cities contains entered name.

I tried to use:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=Poznań&types=(cities)&language=pl&key=[MyKey]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=Pozna%C5%84&types=(cities)&language=pl&key=%5BMyKey%5D)

This request returned 5 cities:

- "Poznań, Polska"
- "Poznanovec, Chorwacja",
- "Poznań, Obwód rówieński, Ukraina"
- "Poznanovci, Słowenia"
- "Sady, Polska"

Two problems:

- Query don't return one of city Poznań in Poland (https://goo.gl/maps/B3LjyRdVn7S3DEuu7)
- I don't know why query return: "Sady, Polska"

Could you tell me how force API to return all cities contains some name?

Full query return:

```json
{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Poznań, Polska",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJtwrh7NJEBEcR0b80A5gx6qQ",
         "reference" : "ChIJtwrh7NJEBEcR0b80A5gx6qQ",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Poznań",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Polska"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Poznań"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 8,
               "value" : "Polska"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Poznanovec, Chorwacja",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJMduuD-nmZUcRKLHqfF4Ty0w",
         "reference" : "ChIJMduuD-nmZUcRKLHqfF4Ty0w",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Poznanovec",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Chorwacja"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Poznanovec"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Chorwacja"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Poznań, Obwód rówieński, Ukraina",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJM8yYp2JZKEcRROf2JFonEiA",
         "reference" : "ChIJM8yYp2JZKEcRROf2JFonEiA",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Poznań",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Obwód rówieński, Ukraina"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Poznań"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 8,
               "value" : "Obwód rówieński"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 25,
               "value" : "Ukraina"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Poznanovci, Słowenia",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 6,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJs5Z1s_IXb0cRGcz67oYV9SA",
         "reference" : "ChIJs5Z1s_IXb0cRGcz67oYV9SA",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Poznanovci",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 6,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Słowenia"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Poznanovci"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 12,
               "value" : "Słowenia"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
      {
         "description" : "Sady, Polska",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 4,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-TKnSCVHBEcRGR5C_UOhHhY",
         "reference" : "ChIJ-TKnSCVHBEcRGR5C_UOhHhY",
         "structured_formatting" : {
            "main_text" : "Sady",
            "main_text_matched_substrings" : [
               {
                  "length" : 4,
                  "offset" : 0
               }
            ],
            "secondary_text" : "Polska"
         },
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Sady"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 6,
               "value" : "Polska"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774299/set-componentrestrictions-with-google-place-autocomplete-api

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796293/restricting-google-places-autocomplete-api-to-specific-countries

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373930/how-to-get-results-of-autocomplete-maps-only-one-country

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set componentRestrictions with Google Place Autocomplete API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774299/set-componentrestrictions-with-google-place-autocomplete-api)

Answer (score -2):

You can add `components` parameter to guarantee that the results of the Places Autocomplete API will be restricted to a certain country.

Here's a working example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?&input=Poznań&types=(cities)&components=country:PL&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

There,`Poznań, Poland` is in the result, and no `Sady, Polska`.